# Estimate $\lambda\frac{|f-\lambda f|^2}p$ without looping twice

Tags: estimation, sampling, monte-carlo, unbiased-estimator, numerical-integration

Let $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ be a measure space, $p$ be a probability density on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ and $f\in\mathcal L^2(\lambda)$. Say I want to estimate $$\int_{\{\:p\:>\:0\:\}}\frac{|f-\lambda f|^2}p\:{\rm d}\lambda.\tag1$$ If $(E_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is any estimator for $\lambda f$, we can estimate $(1)$ by $$\Sigma_n:=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\left(\frac{|f-E_n|}p\right)^2(X_i)\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N,$$ where $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an $E$-valued independent process with $X_n\sim(p\lambda)$ for all $n\in\mathbb N$.

Assume that, unfortunately, $(E_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is not already available and hence we need to form it as well. Clearly, we can choose $$E_n:=\frac1n\sum_{i=1}^n\frac fp(X_i)\;\;\;\text{for }n\in\mathbb N.$$ However, a naive implementation would need to precompute $E_n$ and compute $\Sigma_n$ afterwards and hence implement two loops from $1$ to $n$. Can we do better?

Comment: I understand $\lambda$ to be the probability measure on $E.$  How am I to understand (and make sense of) the expression "$\lambda f$" in the integrand, then?  Indeed, your integral is missing some key parts expected in any integral notation, something like a "$dp$" or "$d\lambda$."  What you're trying to do is obscure.

Comment: @whuber Sorry, added the missing ${\rm d}\lambda$ in $(1)$. $\lambda$ is a ($\sigma$-finite) measure, not necessarily a probability measure.

Comment: What, then, could "$\lambda f$" mean and how is "$p$" related to it and $\lambda$ in the integral?

Comment: @whuber As usual, $\lambda f:=\int f\:{\rm d}\lambda$. And, as written in the question, $p$ is a probability density on $(E,\mathcal E,\lambda)$ which means that $p:E\to[0,\infty)$ is $\mathcal E$-measurable and $\lambda p=1$.

Comment: Are you perhaps supposing $p$ is absolutely continuous w.r.t. $\lambda$ so that we can make sense of dividing a function by $p$?  Maybe $p$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of a measure w.r.t. $\lambda$?  Given that your question ultimately is a question about computing, and thereby focuses on a discrete structure, this setup looks like an unnecessarily abstract and obscure way of stating a question! Indeed, I suspect an effort to simplify the formulation might expose a simple solution.

Comment: @whuber Well, $p\lambda$ is trivially absolutely continuous wrt $\lambda$ and the Radon-Nikodým derivative is $p$. This is the very definition of a probability density. (Just out of curiosity: Which background do you have? It seems like you know a lot about statistics, but we repeatedly run into misunderstandings in theoretical things that seem trivial to me.)

Comment: It's not a matter of misunderstanding but of communication. My problem is that I am aware of many different conventions and terminologies from fields ranging from mathematics to statistics, CS, sciences and social sciences and so on, so I often find ambiguity where people think things are obvious and "trivial." What you might think of as a universal definition, concept, or notation may be highly specialized. As a moderator it's my job to keep all reasonable possible interpretations in mind and ask those who have more focused backgrounds to clarify and explain themselves as much as possible.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for clarifying. (Just to be sure: I didn't tried to offend you.)

Comment: @Xi'an Yes, it's related to that.

Comment: @Xi'an Sorry, I don't get it. The $i$th term is $\frac{|f(X_i)|^2-2f(X_i)E_n+|E_n|^2}{p(X_i)}$ and $E_n=\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n\frac fp(X_j)$. So, in the computation of the $i$th term, we already need to know what the sum up to $n$ is. What am I missing?

Comment: @Xi'an But I don't understand why. Could you explicitly write how your loop would look like?

Comment: @Xi'an Did you delete your answer cause there was a problem you (and in that case I as well) didn't noticed so far?

Comment: @Xi'an I'd still be interested on this.

Comment: Sorry but we do not seem to understand each other on that problem, so let us hope someone else will post a clearer answer.

Comment: @Xi'an Actually, I agreed with your answer except for a left typo. That's why I'm so confused that you deleted it.